# What is the best way to store color hex values in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to store some hexadecimal colors for my items like `#fff`, `#fafafa`, `red`. What is the best type should I use for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `String` and add some validation to make sure the input is of the correct type:

```
COLORS = ['red', 'blue', ...];

function colorValidator (v) {
    if (v.indexOf('#') == 0) {
        if (v.length == 7) {  // #f0f0f0
            return true;
        } else if (v.length == 4) {  // #fff
            return true;
        }
    }
    return COLORS.indexOf(v) > -1;
};

new Schema({
    color: { type: String, validate: [colorValidator, 'not a valid color'] }
});
```

I wrote the `colorValidator` quickly to help you get an idea but you can easily extend it to get a more sophisticated color verification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `validator` with a regular expression test:

```
const colorValidator = (v) => (/^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i).test(v)

const schema = new Schema({
  color: {
    type: String,
    validator: [colorValidator, 'Invalid color'],
    required: true,
  },
});
```

It matches `#fff` `#ffffff` `#FFF` `#FFFFFF` (3 and 6 digits, case insensitive).